# Parsing JSON data from textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to be able to drop JSON formatted data into a textarea to be able to pull out one piece of data at a time. Currently I am just trying to get the names output to a DIV. This is a static HTML file with one textarea, one button and 1 DIV. I am not getting any output which I do not understand. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function parser(){
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var information = document.getElementById("TTP");
            var data = JSON.parse("information");
            results.innerHTML = "";
            for(var obj in data){
                results.innerHTML += data[obj].user+" is present +"<br />";
            }
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="TTP"></textarea>
<div id="results"></div>
<input type="button" onClick="parser()" value="Run"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON Data

```
{ "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" },
{ "user":"Will", "age":27, "country":"United Kingdom" },
{ "user":"Abiel", "age":19, "country":"Mexico" }, 
{ "user":"Rick", "age":34, "country":"Panama" },
{ "user":"Susan", "age":23, "country":"Germany" },
{ "user":"Amy", "age":43, "country":"France" },
{ "user":"Pete", "age":18, "country":"Italy" },
{ "user":"Chris", "age":25, "country":"United States" },
{ "user":"Louis", "age":31, "country":"Spain" },
{ "user":"Emily", "age":38, "country":"Uraguay" },
{ "user":"Shawn", "age":52, "country":"Chile" },
{ "user":"Greg", "age":24, "country":"Romania" }
```

Comment: `JSON.parse("information");` => Uncaught SyntaxError

Comment: You're passing the string `information` not the value of the textbox

Comment: Syntax error with this line: `data[obj].user+" is present +"<br />";` Should be `data[obj].user+" is present" +"<br />";` or you could simplify it to be `data[obj].user+" is present<br />";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function parser(){
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var information = document.getElementById("TTP").value;             // <-- 1
            var data = JSON.parse(information);                         // <-- 2
            results.innerHTML = "";
            for(var obj in data){
                results.innerHTML += data[obj].user+" is present <br>"; // <-- 3
            }
    //results.innerHTML = "requesting...";                              // <-- 4
}
```

```html
<textarea id="TTP">[{ "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" },
{ "user":"Will", "age":27, "country":"United Kingdom" },
{ "user":"Abiel", "age":19, "country":"Mexico" }, 
{ "user":"Rick", "age":34, "country":"Panama" },
{ "user":"Susan", "age":23, "country":"Germany" },
{ "user":"Amy", "age":43, "country":"France" },
{ "user":"Pete", "age":18, "country":"Italy" },
{ "user":"Chris", "age":25, "country":"United States" },
{ "user":"Louis", "age":31, "country":"Spain" },
{ "user":"Emily", "age":38, "country":"Uraguay" },
{ "user":"Shawn", "age":52, "country":"Chile" },
{ "user":"Greg", "age":24, "country":"Romania" }]</textarea>
<div id="results"></div>
<input type="button" onClick="parser()" value="Run"></input>
```

Changes:

1. `document.getElementById()` gets an element, you need its `value`
2. `"information"` is a string, `information` is the variable you want to parse
3. `" is present +"<br />"` was not a correct string
4. The "requesting..." string overwrote the result, it is commented now
5. Your JSON is not a JSON, it needs surrounding `[]`-s to become a list

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues in your code, the main one being your parsing of *information*

You're passing the literal string `"information"` instead of the value of the text box

The other issues are with your string concatenation as pointed out by Nick Parsons, and with the line `results.innerHTML = "requesting...";` as this will just *override* what your for loop has set

```js
function parser() {
  var results = document.getElementById("results");
  var information = document.getElementById("TTP");
  var data = JSON.parse(information.value);
  results.innerHTML = "";
  for (var obj in data) {
    results.innerHTML += data[obj].user + " is present <br/> ";
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="TTP"></textarea>
<div id="results"></div>
<input type="button" onClick="parser()" value="Run"></input>
```

P.S you will have to wrap your dataset in `[]` to denote it's an array